# Rotas react react-router-dom

Tags: react

Estou iniciando no react e estou tentando criar links de navegação interna. Estou na duvida se estou fazendo da forma correta.
criei o arquivo routes

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Profile } from '../components/Profile';
import { Skills } from '../components/Skills'

export default function Routes (){
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" element={Profile} />
                <Route path="/skills" element={Skills} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
            
    );
};
```

Importei o arquivo Routes no index

```
import { Education } from '../components/Education'
import { Experience } from '../components/Experience'
import { NavigationBar } from '../components/NavigationBar'
import { Profile } from '../components/Profile'
import { Skills } from '../components/Skills'
import Routes from './routes'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <NavigationBar />
      </header>

      <section>
        <Profile />
      </section>

      <section>
        <Skills />
      </section>

      <section>
        <Education />
      </section>

      <section>
        <Experience />
      </section>

      <footer>
        <Contacts />
      </footer>
      <Routes />
    </div>
  )
}
```

E estou tentando usar ele na minha navbar

```
import styles from '../styles/components/NavigationBar.module.css'
import './Skills.tsx'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


export function NavigationBar() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.navBar}>
            <Link to="/"><h3>Inicio</h3></Link>
            <nav>
                <ul className={styles.navLinks}>
                    <li><Link to="/skills">Habilidades</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Segue meu app

```
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/globals.css'


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
export default MyApp
```

Estou tendo o seguinte erro

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai precisar envolver as tag BrowserRouter em toda aplicação, segue exemplo abaixo.

E não precisa declarar novamente as paginas no seu Home, pois elas serão renderizadas conforme a rota:

```
    import { Education } from '../components/Education'
    import { Experience } from '../components/Experience'
    import { NavigationBar } from '../components/NavigationBar'
    import { Profile } from '../components/Profile'
    import { Skills } from '../components/Skills'
    import Routes from './routes'
    
    export default function Home() {   return (
    <BrowserRouter>
       <div>
          <header>
             <NavigationBar />
          </header>
          <Routes />
          </div>
    </BrowserRouter>   ) }
```